# Is there any way to integrate Bancontact and ideal using stripe in Shopify

Tags: stripe-payments, shopify, shopify-app

I have a Shopify store and I want to integrate Bancontact and Ideal in Shopify store using stripe. So the customer can pay using Bancontact and ideal on the checkout. I have researched a lot but found only two options

```
1- techtolia https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lW4Lo_qIGc0
2- cardDNA https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2pTBWdDsFw
```

The first one is providing a Code Canyon script with no source code at a very high price. Second one is looking fake.

Comment: https://techtolia.com/ShopifyStripe/ by directing your customers to your own checkout application with an indirect integration like in this demo, you can accept payments with all payment methods supported by Stripe according to your merchant account country and currency.